# C# Discord get my own messages in real time

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am familiar with Discord Api and I handling requests using a Bot.
However, I need now just to get my user messages (not a bot), and handle the corresponding events.
I am using discord .net but I am not able to find a clear example for this task, that should be simple...

1. For a bot, I need to create an application in the dev portal. Do I need the same if I just want it for my user?
2. Discord gateway https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway is the best option I guess. This example uses javascript with websockets, and no other configuration is required beside the auth token of the guild: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo7ugT_XQKk

Any example about how to read the own user messages in C#?

Comment: That tutorial and your request is against Discord terms of service. DNet does not support user bots or connecting to the gateway without a valid bot application.

Comment: Why against Discord terms of service? I do not want to avoid creating an application or provide auth token if it's required. I just would like to do get my user messages, for a guild that I am joining. So, I am doing the same with a bot dealing with the terms. But how to do it as a user?

Comment: Automated user accounts or user bots are against the terms of services. Also, now that message contents are a privileged intent, you would be bypassing restrictions that they attempted to put in place to prevent unauthorized logging of server messages. Bots have to be granted perms to read messages when added to a server and if they are in more than 100 servers, Discord has to approve their use of the message intent. By having your user account do this instead, you would be circumventing these privacy protocols.